# number formatting javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem with formatting my numbers. I found a script on this forum that I will show below this text. It does work with the comma, but when I add a number like `10000000.00`, it will become `10000000,00`, but if I add a number like `10333333.00`, it will become: `10 33 33 33,00`, and that is not what I want. I want to have my number format like this: `10 333 333,00` .

I have been searching for a long time for a solution on this. I tried to change the regex, but i am not that good yet with regex, so i hope someone can help me with this problem.

this is the script:

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    var x = nStr.split('.');
    var x1 = x[0];
    var x2 = x.length > 1 ? ',' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d+{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ' ' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Comment: http://ntt.cc/2008/04/25/6-very-basic-but-very-useful-javascript-number-format-functions-for-web-developers.html

Comment: Please always link to the post where you found the snippet - but thanks for telling us you copied it anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var tests =
[
3141,
314159,
31415926,
10000000.001,
10333333.002,
42121.1415926535
],
res,
i;

function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    var x = nStr.split('.');
    var x1 = x[0];
    var x2 = x.length > 1 ? ',' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1 $2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}

for (i = 0; i < tests.length; i++)
{
  document.write(addCommas(tests[i]) + '<br>');
}
```

The `\d+{3}` was odd and rejected by JSLint (and not working on Firefox).

Code tested on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhiLho/L6q8u/2/).